# Hibernate: How to load embed xml at runtime with "embed-xml=false"

Tags: hibernate, associations, dom4j

The embed xml data will be loaded if embed-xml=true. Is it possible that still load the embed data through modify embed-xml as true dynamically? I want to define the mapping as false in mapping file. Then no many db call at most time since the embed data is not need usually. For some scenarios, load embed data on demand. It can be done through creating two mapping definitions for same entity. Is there better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have got the answer. If the association attribute is not include in select clause, the association table won't be touched even "embed-xml=true".